# errors being displayed on my wordpress site even though i have set the value to off

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, web-hosting, directadmin

i have a wordpress site that displays these 2 warnings on the top of the site:

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /home/[user]/domains/[domainname]/public_html/wp-content/themes/[theme-name]/config-templatebuilder/avia-shortcodes/slideshow_layerslider/slideshow_layerslider[dot]php on line 28
>
> Warning: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect File(/home/admin/domains/[domain]/public_html/wp-content/uploads) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/[Username]/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/alt/php74/usr/share/pear/:/dev/urandom:/usr/local/lib/php/:/usr/local/php74/lib/php/) in /home/[user]/domains/[domain]/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpmu-dev-seo/includes/core/core[dot]php on line 875.

i don't have the intention of actually debugging the warnings for the time being, i just don't want them displayed

I have set the value of display_Errors in php setting (php.ini) of my directadmin panel to off and i have also added these codes in wp-config.php:

> define('WP_DEBUG', false);
>
> ini_set('display_errors', 0);
>
> ini_set ( 'error_reporting', E_ALL );
>
> define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

and yet the error are still being displayed for some reasons, could anyone help me solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue temporarily by changing my PHP version from `alt` to `ea` by adding this command in `.htaccess`:

```xml
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to directly modify the php.ini file.
The line is:

```
php_admin_value open_basedir none
```